# How to set UIButton target

Tags: jquery, html, uibutton

I'm new on this topic...

In my site there is an UIButton,

as like- 
`<p><button id="pay_gateway_button" class="uiButton btn-space"><span><span>Pay Online</span></span></button></p>`

When i'm clicking on this button this opening in self window. But i want to set the target of this button to new window, I mean `target="_blank"` but i don't know how to do this. Any body can help me that which code needs to be write here...!

Answer (score 0):

You can put the button tag into a link tag that will send you to a blank page if the button isn't part of a form

```
<p><a href="#" target="_blank"><button id="pay_gateway_button" class="uiButton btn-space"><span><span>Pay Online</span></span></button></a></p>
```

Comment: after adding a link tag when I clicked on the button, its working two ways, 1. it start self action in the same window.
2. It just opening a new window and nothing happened there after.

Comment: you want to blank the page if the user clicks the button?

Comment: i want the button on click user will be sent to the new window and the button action will work here (in this new window).

Comment: can't figure it out i need more code i think you have a js that is interfiring with the button or the buton is a part of a form

Comment: if you have a form you need to transfer the function that is performing the form submition to another page and link that page in the form action

Comment: This is not a part of any form.
 This is a Button that called an action for the payment page..

Comment: remove id and classes you have a script that is hooking some action with this button

Comment: The id is to called the required action by the button, so it can't be remove.

Is there any way to just add the target attribute to the button using js or any other process...?

Comment: the only solution is altering the js that is called by cliking the button

Comment: Have you any suggestion...?

Comment: i don't have the code in front of me so i can't help you